# Laravel eager load a relationship based on the result of relationship method

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following entities:

**User**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'members';
protected $primaryKey = 'member_id';

public function licences(){
    return $this->hasMany('Licence', 'subid', 'member_id');
}
```

}

**Licence**

```
class Licence extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'licence';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $active = false;

const DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d';

protected $fillable = [];

public function __construct(){
    $this->checkifIsActive();
}

public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'member_id', 'subid');
}

public function checkifIsActive(){
    if($this->start_date <= date($this->DATE_FORMAT) && $this->end_date >= date($this->DATE_FORMAT)) $this->active = true;
}
```

}

One user can have many licences, and the licenses that the user has may be either active or inactive - this is determined by a start and end date on the licence.

I'm trying to load a User object, and at the same time pull in their licences, but only those that are active.

Within the licence model, I am setting the 'active' variable to true, when the object is instantiated, so we have a way of knowing the status of the licence.

The code so far that I've tried is:

```
return User::findOrFail($id)->with('licence.active')->get();
```

However, this is not quite right - as there's no actual condition check done on the 'licence.active'.

How would I return a user, loaded by an ID, along with the licences they have associated that are have a boolean 'active' variable set to 'true'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eager loading constraints to query the relation like so;

```
$user = User::with(array('license' => function($query){
    $query->where('start', '<=', Carbon::now())
    $query->where('end', '>=', Carbon::now())
}))->find($id);
```

This will then only return the licenses that are active.

Optionally you could query the result of the relationship like so;

```
public function activeLicences(){
    return $this->hasMany('Licence', 'subid', 'member_id')->where('start', '<=', Carbon::now())->where('end', '>=', Carbon::now());
}
```

Then all you would have to do is the following to get the results;

```
$user = User::with('activeLicenses')->find($id)
```

**Please Note**: This has not been tested.

Comment: You've passed $id as a parameter to the get method, which expects column names rather than an ID to load.

Comment: Which of the two approaches would you say is the best? I realise they both achieve the same result, but in terms of code quality which would you use?